# reshape dataframe based on a string split in one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have the following data structure

```
ID  Type  Values
1   A     5; 7; 8
2   A     6
3   B     2; 3
```

and I would like to reshape it to the following using R:

```
ID  Type  Values
1   A     5
1   A     7
1   A     8
2   A     6
3   B     2
3   B     3
```

I've been trying to work out how to do it with plyr but without any success.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you asked for a `plyr` solution, here you go:

```
ddply(df, .(Type), function(foo) {
    values <- unlist(strsplit(c(foo$Values), ";"))
    data.frame(Type = rep(unique(foo$Type), length(values)), Values = values)
    })
```

Comment: I figured this one would be tough for plyr.  Not so, thanks for proving my thought wrong. +1

Answer (score 6):

A `data.table` approach for coding elegance

```
library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(dat)
DT[, list(Value = unlist(strsplit(as.character(Values), '; '))), by = list(ID, Type)]
```

Answer (score 2):

My shot:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, 
                type = c("A", "A", "B"), 
                values = c("5; 7; 8", "6", "2; 3"))

g <- strsplit(as.character(a$values), ";")
data.frame(id = rep(a$id, lapply(g, length)), 
            type = rep(a$type, lapply(g, length)),
            values = unlist(g))
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a beautiful answer but it could be useful

```
DF <- data.frame(ID=1:3,
                 Type=c('A','A','B'), 
                 Values=c(' 5; 7; 8', '6', ' 2;3')) # this is your df

    # split vectors and coercing values to be numeric
    List <- lapply(strsplit(Values, ';'), as.numeric)

# The desired output
    data.frame(ID=rep(ID, sapply(List, length)), 
               Type=rep(Type, sapply(List, length)),
               Values =   unlist(List))
 ID Type Values
1  1    A      5
2  1    A      7
3  1    A      8
4  2    A      6
5  3    B      2
6  3    B      3
```

Comment: Funny, I ended up with almost exact solution!

Answer (score 1):

The answers so far are great. Here's yet another.

```
# The data
DF <- data.frame(ID=1:3,
                 Type=c('A','A','B'), 
                 Values=c(' 5; 7; 8', '6', ' 2;3'))
```

This solution uses the `colsplit()` function from the "reshape2" package. One downside is that it expects you to know the number of resulting columns needed.

```
require(reshape2)
DF2 <- data.frame(DF[-3], colsplit(DF$Values, ";", c("V.1", "V.2", "V.3")))
na.omit(melt(DF2, id.vars=c("ID", "Type")))
#   ID Type variable value
# 1  1    A      V.1     5
# 2  2    A      V.1     6
# 3  3    B      V.1     2
# 4  1    A      V.2     7
# 6  3    B      V.2     3
# 7  1    A      V.3     8
```

From here you can sort and drop columns as required to get your final desired output.

Answer (score 0):

This should work but maybe there's a better approach:

```
#recreate data set
dat <- data.frame(ID=1:3, Type=c("A", "A", "B"), Values=c("5; 7; 8", "6", "2; 3"))
#split the Value column by ;
a <- strsplit(as.character(dat$Values), ";", fixed=TRUE)
#remove extra white
a <- lapply(a, function(x) gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", x))
#get the length of each cell in Value so we can use this to index the rows
lens <- sapply(a, length)
#index rows and rename row names to numeric indexes
dat2 <- dat[rep(1:nrow(dat), lens), 1:2]
rownames(dat2) <- NULL
#add the stretched new column back
dat2$Value <- as.numeric(unlist(a))
```